# Section Header For Particular Section Using UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionlayoutlistconfiguration

I have a `UICollectionView` with 2 sections using `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration`. I want to have a Header for only one of those particular sections.

### COLLECTION VIEW

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    var list = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
    list.headerMode = .supplementary
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: list)
    let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    // REGISTER CELLS ETC...
    return view
}()
```

### DATASOURCE

```
dataSource.supplementaryViewProvider = { [weak self] collectionView, kind, indexPath in
    guard let self = self else { return nil }
    
        
    if let section = Section(rawValue: indexPath.section) {
        switch section {
        case .topSection:
            // I DO NOT HAVE ANY HEADER FOR THIS SECTION
        case .bottomSection:
            switch kind {
            case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
                // RETURN SECTION HEADER HERE
            case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:
                // I DO NOT HAVE ANY FOOTERS
            default:
                fatalError("SOMETHING BAD HAPPENED")
            }
        }
    }
```

What can I try next to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.

I needed need to return an `NSCollectionLayoutSection` for each section type in the `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` it cannot be done within the Data Source.

```
private func setUpLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { [unowned self] sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
            let section = Section(rawValue: sectionIndex)
            switch section {
            case .task:
                return self.setUpSection(layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)
            case .project:
                return self.setUpHeaderSection(layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)
            case .completed:
                return self.setUpHeaderSection(layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)
            default:
                return self.setUpHeaderSection(layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)
            }
        }
        return layout
    }
    
private func setUpSection(layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        var listConfiguration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
        listConfiguration.headerMode = .none
        return NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(using: listConfiguration, layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)
    }
    
private func setUpHeaderSection(layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        var listConfiguration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
        listConfiguration.headerMode = .supplementary
        return NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(using: listConfiguration, layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Set header height as zero. for that particular section inside "referenceSizeForHeaderInSection"

Comment: I am using UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource not the conventional UICollectionViewDataSource